# Why "json_encode()" works differently?

Tags: php

I'm fairly new programmer to PHP. I've been doing this "todolist" in my free time and I have noticed something weird.

I have two identical arrays. One was decoded with *json_decode()* function and the other was made with *foreach* cycle. Then I encoded both of the arrays with *json_encode()* function and the results are different.

My actual code:

```
$data = file_get_contents( $file );
$data = json_decode( $data, true );
unset($data[$i]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $data );
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r( json_encode($data) );
echo '</pre>';

$arr = [];
foreach ($data as $item) $arr[] = $item;

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $arr );
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r( json_encode($arr) );
echo '</pre>';

die();
```

[Screenshot of Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIUNr.png)

Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to point out. :(

Update:

The content of the storage file

```
[{"text":"hey","date":1532288364},{"text":"whatsup","date":1532288372}]
```

Comment: lets see the contents of that storage file. the second array is correctly indexed starting at zero. the first one is not.

Comment: Code and samples belong in the question, as text, not pictures. Unless you insist on a GIF answer, of course.

Comment: voted as unclear, up until we have actual code and not images of it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what about now ?

Comment: Perfect @Rattko thank you. (Vote retracted).

Comment: $i is not defined

Comment: @progysm $i is defined above.. I just didn't include the whole code.

Comment: @mario the question is updated, is it better now ?

Comment: if you unset $data[0], and it prints two elements, this means there was three elements in your file. Use array_shift($data)  to reindex elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode()` will create valid JavaScript syntax, which can only support arrays that start at index `0` and have no gaps.

If `json_encode()` detects an array does not meet this criteria, it will encode it as an object, which is exactly the case. Your array starts at index `1` and cannot be converted into a valid JavaScript array.